# Laravel eloquent for joining two tables using a pivot tables

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a User Model with the columns id, name, email
a Course Model with the columns id, name, code
and a pivot table course_user.

Course and User has many-to-many relation

Users can take several  courses. Now I want to get the courses which are not taken by a particular user.
Is there any eloquent for this?

I've searched and tried for 2 hours but got nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`whereDoesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) method:

```
Course::whereDoesntHave('users', function($q) use($userId) {
    $q->where('id', $userId);
})->get();
```

Comment: Can you please explain this?

Comment: @MisbahAhmad I'm not sure about what exactly you want me to explain. If you're not familiar with the method, click the link in my answer to learn more about it. If it's still not clear, please tell me what exactly you want me to explain.